# In OpenCV many conversions to JPG using imEncode fails

Tags: opencv, jpeg, codec

For a specific purpose I am trying to convert an AVI video to a kind of Moving JPEG format using OpenCV. In order to do so I read images from the source video, convert them to JPEG using imEncode, and write these JPEG images to the target video.

After several hundreds of frames suddenly the size of the resulting JPEG image nearly doubles. Here's a list of sizes:

```
68045
68145
68139
67885
67521
67461
67537
67420
67578
67573
67577
67635
67700
67751
127800
127899
127508
127302
126990
126904
```

Anybody got a clue what's going on here?

By the way: I'm using OpenCV.Net as a wrapper for OpenCV.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Paul

Comment: maybe the image content does change? can you show sample images for 68000 kind images and 12500 kind images?

Comment: Sorry, Micka, can't show because of the privacy of the subject in the video. But I checked and the frames exactly before and after the change in size are nearly identical, so the huge difference in size is not caused by a change in the scene. I'm afraid I hit a bug in OpenCV...

Comment: can you try to save those images as .bmp and convert them to jpeg with irfanView, GIMP, Photoshop or something and check the resulting sizes?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Micka, but I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If I explicitly enter the third parameter to imEncode (for JPEG encoding this indicates the quality of the encoding, ranging from 0 to 100) instead of using the default (95) the problem disappears. It's likely this is a bug in OpenCV.Net, but it could also be a bug in OpenCV itself.